# WebClient DownloadFile displaying wrong percentage

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm using a `System.Net.WebClient` to download a file asynchron in my application. For some reason, on some systems the percentage gets wrong calculated.

My (updated) DownloadProgressChanged event:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadProgressChanged += (_sender, _e) => {
    double bytesIn = _e.BytesReceived;
    double totalBytes = _e.TotalBytesToReceive;
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;
    UpdateConnectingStatus("Missionsdatei wird heruntergeladen... (" + Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString() + "%)");
};
```

How it should look like (Windows 8.1 64bit):

[image: How it should look like]

How it looks on some systems (Windows 7 64bit):

[image: How it looks on some systems]

Could it have something to do with the OS? Or any other ideas?

UPDATE: I removed the division (`/ 1000000`) completly, but it doesn't work either on the same system.

UPDATE 2: I checked the value of totalBytes. The result of totalBytes is -1 on the system where it doesnt work. Any ideas why this is so?

UPDATE 3: I still don't have a solution although I tried to remove the string conversion stuff and adding a `.0` to the division. I think it depends on the slow internet connection the person has, at whom it doesn't work.. I now only display the percentage, if it is positive.

Comment: Try dividing by 1000000.0 (with decimal point).  The code may be doing an integer divide and truncating part of the results.  The weird results is a large negative number with the MSB hex numbers being 0xFFFFFF.  It looks like the division is giving an integer instead of a float.

Comment: "Could it have something to do with the OS?" No, the bug is yours with 99.999999% certainty. use the debugger to see at what point values are being computed incorrectly. That funcy string conversion stuff might be the problem, you should remove that in any case.

Comment: If all you are showing is a percentage why are you dividing by `1000000` initially at all? And why are you using to `ToString()` and then parsing the string? Cast or convert it properly.

Comment: Seeing your update: Maybe you should take the hint and remove that wild string conversion stuff. Or, use the debugger to inspect more values.

Comment: Seeing your recent edit: You still have not done what was asked and what's likely to be the solution. You also have not reacted to the comments. Since you are still actively looking for a solution I really don't get why you refuse the help that you asked for. You are causing yourself pain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has repeatedly refused to cooperate.

Comment: No no, please wait. I'm not refusing any help. I tried all the things, but none worked. Sorry if this wasn't clear to everybody. :/

Comment: Is there a difference in where you're downloading them from, i.e is the win 8 machine the development machine and the win 7 machine pulling from a remote address?

Comment: The Win 8 system is my development machine, the win 7 system is the machine of a customer. Both systems download from a Web Server using http. The only difference is the speed of the internet connection. I have about 100 Mbit, but he only has about 6 Mbit or lower.

Comment: Then please refresh the code to the current version. I don't want to see any more double.Parse there! Also remove the `/ 1000000` as they seem to serve no purpose. Let's remove sources of bugs.

Comment: If this does not remove the problem add logging for the values of `_e.TotalBytesToReceive` and the other one. Let's catch the bad value and prove what code is causing it.

Comment: @usr Okay, I updated the code. I don't exactly know what you mean now. I already logged the values of _e.TotalBytesToReceive and _e.BytesReceived (look at update 2). The result was, that _e.TotalBytesToReceive is -1 at the customers machine. On my machine _e.TotalBytesToReceive returns the correct value of the filesize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to some web searching and according to my decompiler `TotalBytesToReceive` can be -1 if the size of the download is not (yet) known. (Yes, this is hideous API design.)

Guard for the -1 case:

```
if (TotalBytesToReceive == -1)
 Print("Download in Progress");
else
 Print(e.ProgressPercent);
```

It is unclear yet why the download size is not known on that one machine. Maybe there is an HTTP proxy removing the `Content-Length` header, or the web server is not sending it for some reason.